# Source for Bikurim being brought from new annual produce as opposed to first time only

Tags: sources-mekorot

I'm looking for a (primary) source stating whether Bikurim is brought from the fruit of a tree every year from its first annual produce, or only from the first time fruits which a person gets from his tree. (After *orlah* and *Netah Revaiy*).

Comment: It's brought from wheat and barley even though there's no Orlah, and each plant is distinct

Comment: @DoubleAA so what if each plant is distinct. It can be brought from each produce whenever it gives the owner crop the first time.If no orlah so the first yr. if orlah and revay so 5th year.

Comment: Rabbi Yisroel Reisman asked the same question and didnt give an answer.

Comment: Gosh. This is one of those questions that you at first glance think is obvious, that sources must be abound...but when you actually look for it nobody actually seems to say it...

Comment: Isn't what you're describing what revay already is?

Comment: Also, what would that mean - that you would have to bring a kernel from every stalk of wheat?

Comment: @Loewian I think he’s asking do you have to take from the first fruits every year, or just the first permissible year?

Comment: Nechemia - 10:36

Answer (score 4):

While the complete answer lies with [the kuntrus](https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=15150&sid=95eff9cbadbca7878376b027e48d43dc) written on the subject, here is some consensus on the topic.

Here are the two contemporary opposing opinions of [Rabbi Eliezer Yehuda Waldenberg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Waldenberg) and [Rabbi Shmaryahu Yosef Chaim Kanievsky](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Kanievsky).

[***Tzitz Eliezer 15:16:3:***](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14514&st=&pgnum=50)

The essence of his argument is on how the Torah is worded. The word *האדמה* (Dev. 26:2) is used to imply that the land (האדמה) needs to have it’s fruits brought. Once brought however, there is no longer a need to do so in the future.

> בפשטות
>   משמע שמספיק הבאת בכורים רק פעם אחת מהפרי שהאדמה שלו נתנה ראשית בכוריה, זאת  אומרת שאין להביא יותר מזה מפני שהראשית בכורים תלוי בראשית בכורי אדמתו, ואם כבר הביא
>   פעם בכזאת תו אין להביא יותר מהאילנות של אדמתו זאת, ואפילו כשבעוד שנה נותנים [האילנות] עוד הפעם פירות חדשים מכל מקום אין לו להביא יותר ראשית הבכורים מזה היות ומאדמתו זאת שהאילנות שלו גדלים שם כבר הביא מראשית בכורים. [דלא נזכר שבכל שנה צריך להביא מתאנה
>   שבכרה, ומשמע שמספיק רק פעם אחת ולא יותר ...
>   ואם צדקנו בדברינו אלה, יתיישב שפיר כמין חומר הקושיא הנ"ל מדוע שלא כתוב מראשית פרי העץ, והיינו מפני שאילו היה כתוב כן היינו יכולים לטעות ולחשוב שצריך תמיד להביא בכורים בכל שנת - עונה שהעץ נותן פריו מחדש הגם שכבר הביא מפריו הקודם בשנה שעברה, ובמיוחד הייתי טועה לומר כן בחטה ובשעורה אשר בכל שנה גדל ממש הכל מחדש, ולכן כתבה התורה בזה בלשון ולקחת מראשית כל פרי האדמה לאשמעינן שהדבר תלוי בהאדמה, ואם האדמה הזאת שלו כבר נתנה ראשית והביא מבכוריה תו אין צריך להביא יותר הגם שהפרי מתחדש וגדל מחדש בכל שנה או יותר.

[***Derech Emunah IIII, Bikurim Ch. 4, Tzitun Halacha 130:***](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?106390&)

One brings every year, based on several sources.

- [Rashi, Dev. 26:16:](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.26.16.2)

  > ושמרת ועשית אותם. בַּת קוֹל מְבָרַכְתּוֹ — הֵבֵאתָ בִכּוּרִים הַיּוֹם, תִּזְכֶּה לְשָׁנָה הַבָּאָה (שם):
  >   ושמרת ועשית אותם
  >
  > THOU SHALT THEREFORE KEEP AND DO THEM — A heavenly voice (בת קול) pronounces by these words a blessing upon him (the worshipper): “You have brought the first fruits today — you will be privileged to do so next year, too!” (Midrash Tanchuma, Ki Tavo 1).
- [Rashi, Gitin 47a:](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Gittin_47a.7.1)

  > מתני' הכי גרסינן לוקח ומביא בכורים - בכל שנה צריך ליקח מן העובד כוכבים ביכורי פירותיה בדמים יקרים ומביאם לירושלים:
  >
  > If one’s field is sold to a non-Jew, he continues to take produce [in monetary value] every year as Bikurim.
- [Rabbi Jonathan ben David ha-Kohen of Lunel, Chulin 135a:](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43541&st=&pgnum=1161&hilite=)

  > ועיקר ראשית הגז
  >   נוהג בכל הגוזז צאנו בין טלאים שלא נגזזו מעולם בין זקנים שנגזזו מאה פעמים וכו' וכן בכל שנה ושנה  מאותן רחלות עצמן לפי שפירוש ראשית הגז לכל פרי השנה ופרי דרחל הוי הצמר שגדל עליה כפירוש
  >   ראשית פרי האדמה שכל שנה ושנה מביא מתאנה אחת בכורים וכן פירוש ראשית דגנך.
  >
  > ...As in every year one brings Bikurim.

Comment: That work is about as thorough as you could hope for. +1